# Amplify Video Add

Tags: video, aws-amplify

I recently ran amplify video add to my react project. I am able to successfully launch the resources. But I am running into two problems:

1. after adding amplify video and creating the resources in our develop branch, any time a collaborating developer is working on a feature branch and runs amplify pull, the video and corresponding function resources are deleted. We have been able to solve for this by deleting existing amplify folder in our directories before pulling from amplify or merging our develop branch into our features branches before merging back to develop. These are workarounds, just wondering if anyone has experienced something similar.
2. some developers are having issues getting the `aws-video-exports.js` file when they pull from the updated amplify. We have been able to manually send this file and add it to the projects.